# Disable Google Search button displayed on the page automatically by Adsense

Tags: html, css, adsense

I have Google Adsense enabled on my web site. On some pages a **Search** button like the following is displayed at a random location on the page:

[image: Search Button]

This button is also staying over page contents when I try to print the page and obscures a part of the content.

I want to disable it during print. I tried to hide it using the following CSS (for `media="print"`):

```css
[class^="autoprose"],
[class^="auto-prose"]
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

It seems to work. However, I am searching for a better solution.

We should blame also Google for forgetting to remove this button on printed web pages.

The code automatically inserted by Google is something like this:

```html
<button class="autoprose-search-button">
 <div class="autoprose-search-icon">
  <svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
   <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.76 10.27L17.49 16L16 17.49L10.27 11.76C9.2 12.53 7.91 13 6.5 13C2.91 13 0 10.09 0 6.5C0 2.91 2.91 0 6.5 0C10.09 0 13 2.91 13 6.5C13 7.91 12.53 9.2 11.76 10.27ZM6.5 2C4.01 2 2 4.01 2 6.5C2 8.99 4.01 11 6.5 11C8.99 11 11 8.99 11 6.5C11 4.01 8.99 2 6.5 2Z" fill="white">
   </path>
  </svg>
 </div>
 <div class="autoprose-search-text">Search</div>
</button>
```

Note that, this **Search** button is not created by any web browser extension (disabling all web browser extensions does not change anything) and it is the same for Firefox, Chrome, and Edge browser. On the other hand, when I remove *all* Adsense code from my page, the **Search** button is no longer displayed.

Comment: Are you sure it's being added by Adsense and not by a browser extension?

Comment: @BrettDonald disabling extensions does not make any difference. I added an explanation at the end of my question.

Comment: It is not a programming related question. You need to turn off the search box from the AdSense dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdSense Lab: Search for Auto ads

Search for Auto ads is an easy-to-deploy search box that will be added to your site. With this tool, users are given access to a Google-powered search experience that shows site search results and AdSense for Search ads.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12490210

Comment: I just missed that subsection in AdSense! Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Adsense Dashboard

Select -> Optimization -> Labs

There, look for '**Turn on Search for Auto ads**'

Turn Off this option

Solved to me